# Is there a way to test AWS Lambda functions more efficiently with watch?

Tags: aws-lambda

Currently I am manually running

1. cdk synth
2. sam local invoke <lambda_name> -t cdk.out/api.template.json -e events/<event_name>.json

I run these two steps every single time and the `cdk synth` takes long time to run. When I develop with other server side Javascript frameworks, I usually start-up the server in "watch" mode so that the changes are applied to the running server immediately. Is there such efficient way to do local development with AWS Lambda functions (in Python)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe `cdk watch` is what you need? See AWS [doc](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/increasing-development-speed-with-cdk-watch/).

Comment: Wow, completely overlooked there is such a command...